# No Syntax highlighting in GLU?

Tags: support

[This answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5653) to [Looking for comprehensive, parsable table of German noun declensions](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/looking-for-comprehensive-parsable-table-of-conjugated-german-nouns) contains some XML code. As I knew of [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) I edited the answer, but still after acceptance by users with enough reputation I don’t see any change! Is this feature deactivated on GLU or is there another explanation (hopefully not an error of mine)?

*I opted for the tag `support` for now. If you are sure, it is actually a bug, feel free to change it.*

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong. GLU, ELU etc. seems to have this feature deactivated.

Comment: @Em1: Thanks for reaction! (BTW: Where are the mods?)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for bringing up this topic. Syntax highlighting is not enabled by default when a site launches to beta.

Being a non-computing language site (where syntax plays a different role) we may not need syntax highlighting too often. To my knwowledge the post you linked to was the first to benefit from prettifying.

It certainly is a matter we have to keep in mind for the final site design once we matured from beta.